# PayPal recurrent payment. How to claim them?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I've been working (or should I say struggling) with the PayPal SDK to get recurring billing running for my website. I managed to get it to work, however I do not see how to automatically "claim" the money?

Basically what happens is:
The profile is created, after 24 hours the payment is done and I see the following in my merchant sandbox account:

[image]

It seems I need to manually accept the payment for the amount to be added to my PayPal balance.
Is there a way of doing this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by an issue with the recipient's account. Most commonly, The recipient hasn’t confirmed the email address on their PayPal account. Once the email address is confirmed the amount would automatically post to the balance on future payments.